# map a function to a list of data frames

Tags: r

In R, Can I use `lapply` or `map` to add a `$year` column to several data frames in a list? I want to have the year in the data frame before melting them.

```
years<-2004:2006
names04<-c("green","q22","yellow")
names05<-c("green","q27","yellow")
names06<-c("green","q29","yellow")
yr2004<-1:3
yr2005<-6:8
yr2006<-8:10

year2004<-rbind(names04,yr2004)
colnames(year2004)<-names04
year2004
year2005<-rbind(names05,yr2005)
colnames(year2005)<-names05
year2006<-rbind(names06,yr2006)
colnames(year2006)<-names06
year2004<-as.data.frame(year2004)
year2005<-as.data.frame(year2005)
year2006<-as.data.frame(year2006)

## rewrite this section with lapply ##
dfs<-list(year2004,year2005,year2006)
year2004$year=2004
year2005$year=2005
year2006$year=2006

library(purrr)
map(cbind,dfs,years)

#where
years <- c(2004, 2005, 2006)
```

> map gives an error: `.x` is not a vector (closure)

Comment: put them in a list and map? `Map(cbind, l1, year = years)` where year is c(2004, 5, 6) and l1 the list with your df

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you put the data frames in a list, you can create a vector with the years and use `Map`, i.e.

```
dfs <- list(year2004, year2005, year2006)
years <- c(2004, 2005, 2006)

Map(cbind, dfs, year = years)

#[[1]]
#        green q22 yellow year
#names04 green q22 yellow 2004
#yr2004      1   2      3 2004

#[[2]]
#        green q27 yellow year
#names05 green q27 yellow 2005
#yr2005      6   7      8 2005

#[[3]]
#        green q29 yellow year
#names06 green q29 yellow 2006
#yr2006      8   9     10 2006
```

Note that the `map` you are using in your question is from `purrr(package)`, hence the error

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map2 function from the purrr package as well. Map from purrr only takes one input argument whereas map2 can take multiple arguments

```
library(purrr)

dfs <- list(year2004, year2005, year2006)

years <- c(2004, 2005, 2006)

map2(dfs, years, function(df, year) {
  cbind(df, year)
})
```